# Apache conflict on Microsoft Server 2012 R2

Tags: apache, windows-server-2012-r2

I use Apache Topcat on Microsoft Server 2012 R2 for my site.

My site domain doesnt work without :8080 .

www.mysite.com gives error. Error is "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

But in www.mysite.com:8080 there is no any problem.

I think that IIS on Microsoft Server 2012 R2 uses 8080 port.

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should find all services that are working on :80 port.

1) In command prompt write "netstat -aon " and find which services are using port :80

2) In command prompt write "services.msc" Disable all services that use :80 port and make the start-up type Manuel.

3) In .\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf open server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Change port to : port="80"

4) Restart your server.

5) Start apache and your problem will be solverd.